# Regex capture groups and use OR statement

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex expression that has has multiple conditions separated by `|` (OR). I want to use capture groups but I'm not getting it to work fully.

3 sample strings:

```
--- {source-charset: '', encoding-error-limit: '', class: stat-direct, directory: \\\myserver\C\FOLDER\SUB_FOLDER}  
--- {odbc-connect-string-extras: '', server: hello.sample.com, dbname: X_DB, port: '80', class: hello, username: USERX}  
--- {cleaning: 'no', filename: //myserver/D/FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER/File name.xlsx, dataRefreshTime: '', interpretationMode: '0'}
```

For each sample string I would like the regex to return:

```
\\\myserver\C\FOLDER\SUB_FOLDER  
X_DB  
//myserver/D/FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER/File name.xlsx
```

Basically the value after either `directory:`, `dbname:` or `filename:` and ending with `}` for one of them and `,` for two.

I've managed to use OR statements to get the three conditions in.
regex extract

```
'directory: [^}]+|dbname: [^,]+|filename: [^,]+'
```

That returns:

```
directory: \\\myserver\C\FOLDER\SUB_FOLDER}  
dbname: X__DB,  
filename: //myserver/D/FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER/File name.xlsx,
```

If I introduce capturing groups I only get the right return for one of the parts:
    'directory: ([^}]+)|dbname: ([^,]+)|filename: ([^,]+)'

That returns:

```
\\\myserver\C\FOLDER\SUB_FOLDER  
null  
null
```

I've managed to get it working with a nested regex that takes the result from

```
'directory: [^}]+|dbname: [^,]+|filename: [^,]+'
```

and uses:

```
': ([^,}]+)'
```

That gives me the result I want but I would like to do this as one regex.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

/Aron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match not a `{`, `}` or a comma, match any of the options in a non capturing group and use and a single capturing group the capture the values:

```
{[^{]+(?:filename|directory|dbname): ([^,}]+)[^}]*}
```

**Explanation**

- `{` Match {
- `[^{]+` Match 1+ times not { using a negated character class
- `(?:filename|directory|dbname):`  Match any of the listed options followed by : and a space
- `(` Capture group1

  - `[^,}]+` Match 1+ times not `,` or `}`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^}]*}` Match 0+ times not `}`, then match `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UyGAb0/1)

Comment: Beautiful, worked like a charm. Thank you so much. And thank you for the step-by-step walkthrough!